# in pymongo query where in i want to fetch specific data from nested document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have below document stored in mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c13b65ef169123748e18ecb"),
    "Countries" : [ 
        {
            "States" : [ 
                {
                    "Cities" : [ 
                        "Eshkashem", 
                        "Fayzabad", 
                        "Jurm", 
                        "Khandud", 
                        "Qal'eh-ye Panjeh"
                    ],
                    "StateName" : "Badakhshan"
                }, 
                {
                    "Cities" : [ 
                        "Bala Morghab", 
                        "Qal'eh-ye Naw"
                    ],
                    "StateName" : "Badgis"
                }
            ],
            "CountryName" : "Afghanistan"
        }, 
        {
            "States" : [ 
                {
                    "Cities" : [ 
                        "Berat", 
                        "Polican", 
                        "Ure Vajgurore"
                    ],
                    "StateName" : "Berat"
                }, 
                {
                    "Cities" : [ 
                        "Bulqize"
                    ],
                    "StateName" : "Bulqize"
                }
            ],
            "CountryName" : "Albania"
        }
    ]
}
```

what I want is, I want to fetch data whose countryName is Afganisthan

I have tried bleow query

```
loc_country = loc.find({"Countries.CountryName":"Afghanistan"})
```

but it gives all the record instead of only Afganisthan

Please help me I am stucked.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/):

```
loc_country = loc.find(
   { "Countries.CountryName":"Afghanistan"},
   { 'Countries.$': 1 }
)
```

If possible, you should consider a data model with one country per document for easier lookup. (If it makes sense)